# How to stop a button access in php?

Tags: php

I Have a button which can only be accessed if a manager logins and not an junior employee. I want to restrict the access of it. I am taking a `SessionVariable` to check but it doesn't seems to be working.
I have assigned access value 1 for a manager where I am checking Login credentials-

```
if ($_SESSION["AccessValue"] != 1)
{
    header("Refresh:0; url=HomePage.php");
}
```

Comment: A button can be clicked IMHO, but not be accessed (maybe there is a language barrier here). I don't either see the button nor the `SessionVariable` here. Can you expand your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `location`:

```
if ($_SESSION['AccessValue'] != 1) {
    header('Location: homePage.php');
}
```

see here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Though I'd much rather recommend hiding the button entirely from junior rather than preventing action of click.

e.g.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['AccessValue'] == 1) : ?>
    <button type="button" etc etc.>Click me</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't know why this isn't working for me.

Comment: Below option is better. First one doesn't works for me.

Comment: @check glad I could help :) and not sure about why first one wouldn't work but hey ho :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button itself for a Junior

```
if ($_SESSION["AccessValue"] != 1)
{
    $disable_btn = 'disabled = "disabled"';
}else{
   $disabled_btn= '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<button <?php echo $disabled_btn; ?> ></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the cookie of session first using :
`setcookie(session_id(),session_name(),time()+3600*72);`
And for every time that you want access session you should start session using `session_start();`
Now for time that you specified (3600*72) the session will be able to access for that user and if she/he login the session will be accessible.
And after that you can use this session like a condition for echo the button tag or disable and enable that

> `if(isset($_SESSION('NAME'))`
>            `$status=$_SESSION('NAME');`
>   `<button ....<?php if ($status!=1)echo "disabled";?>.....>`
>           `button_name</button>`

Comment: never recommend cookies - they have security flaws and are a lot easier to target than sessions (though sessions are prone to attacks, this can be dealt with easily)